# How To Erase and Overwrite Data in Spi EEPROM

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, spi, flash-memory, eeprom

I am using WinBond W25Q64JV SPI Flash chip for storing data and micro controller is STM32F101RCT6. When i am try to store the data in Winbond chip it is working fine i can able to read and write data in winbond chip but if i want to overwrite the new data in same address it is not overwrite and it is giving the old data that is new data is not written in same memory.If i use the erase option it is erase all data in all address location i am unable to erase particular address data. After all address data erased i can able to write the new data but i am losing the data in all other locations so please guide me to overwrite the new data in same address location/ Erase option for particular address my code is below

```
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CHIP_SELECT_GPIO_Port, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
     HAL_Delay(1000);
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CHIP_SELECT_GPIO_Port, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
     Spi_data[0]=0x06;  //Write Enable
     HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2,Spi_data,1,1000);
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CHIP_SELECT_GPIO_Port, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CHIP_SELECT_GPIO_Port, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET); 
     Spi_data[0]=0x02; //Page Program
     Spi_data[1]=0x00;
     Spi_data[2]=0x10;
     Spi_data[3]=0x14;
     Spi_data[4]=0x43;
     HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2,Spi_data,5,10000);
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CHIP_SELECT_GPIO_Port, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CHIP_SELECT_GPIO_Port, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
     Spi_data[0]=0x03;//Read Data
     Spi_data[1]=0x00;
     Spi_data[2]=0x10;
     Spi_data[3]=0x14;
     HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2,Spi_data,4,100);
     HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi2,GSdata,4,100);
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CHIP_SELECT_GPIO_Port, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
```

when i am try to overwrite the new data in 0x1014 location it is not overwritten if i am use the following erase option it is erase all memory address data

```
   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CHIP_SELECT_GPIO_Port, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
   Spi_data[0]=0x20;//Erase
   Spi_data[1]=0x00;
   Spi_data[2]=0x10;
   Spi_data[3]=0x14;
   HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2,Spi_data,4,1000);
   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(CHIP_SELECT_GPIO_Port, CHIP_SELECT_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
```

please guide me to overwrite the new data in same address/Erase option for particular address

Comment: If you need to rewrite a portion of a sector you can read the entire section into RAM, erase the sector, and then rewrite the modified sector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the product datasheet

> **8.3 Sector Erase (20h)**
>
> The Sector Erase instruction sets all memory within a specified sector (4K-bytes) to the erased state of all 1s
> (FFh).

This is a flash memory, not an eeprom, therefore there's a minimum erase block size, which is 4 kilobytes. There's no way to erase individual bytes.

Answer (score 0):

W25Q64JV has 64 mbit  = 8 mbyte
each sector has 4 kbytes size then you have 2000 sector or 0x7d0
so the maximum address you can erase is 0x7d0

you want to erase 0x1014 this byte is on sector 2
then you should erase sector 0x2 but every other bytes in this sector erase too
you can copy sector 2 in array then erase sector 2 and after that write array in to this sector